# Hibernate 4.2.2 session factory error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So i'm working on a project lately, i'm using hibernate with a mysql database.

after setting things up, i wanted to test my dao, but when i run the test, i get this error :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:64)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.isEnabled(Log4jLogger.java:39)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logv(Logger.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger_$logger.tracev(CoreMessageLogger_$logger.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:58)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    at example.Utils.SessionFactorySingleton.createSession(SessionFactorySingleton.java:19)
    at example.Utils.SessionFactorySingleton.getSessionFactory(SessionFactorySingleton.java:30)
    at example.dao.BookDaoImpl.<init>(BookDaoImpl.java:17)
    at example.Main.main(Main.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I already searched the net without finding a solution. I feel like it's not really related to hibernate but i want to make sure.

Here's my SessionFactorySingleton :

```
public class SessionFactorySingleton {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static void createSession() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            createSession();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any logging framework added to your project dependencies? May be this is a logger compatibility issue.

Comment: Actually, I just deleted the log4j jar, and it's working :) Well not exactly but, at least i don't have this problem anymore, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any logging framework(/s) added to your project dependencies? May be this is a logger compatibility issue. Please review the logger added is compatible with Hibernate.